# Is there a KairosDB component for Apache Camel?

Tags: apache-camel, kairosdb

I can't find a Camel component for KairosDB. Is there none?

Should I write a custom component or is there a smarter way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official component for that. You can find the list of components at: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components#components

Yes you would need to write your own component, or just use regular Java code in a Java bean to integrate with KairosDB and then Camel can integrate with your Java bean. Or use a Camel Processor instead of a Java bean.

But writing a component is not so hard, and if you use KairosDB in more projects with Camel then it starts to make sense to build a Camel component for it. The Apache Camel project loves contributions: http://camel.apache.org/contributing